# Need info on oracle driver compatibility

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, powerbuilder

I am a newbie to oracle database, could anyone please help me here.

I can not find drivers for **oracle 9.2** so i used **oracle 10g** instead. i am also able to connect to database but when i am querying; i am not getting any results. (I am using Powerbuilder 12.6 for development)

Apparently i would like to know compatibility of oracle drivers. Does Oracle 10g drivers supports oracle 9i ?

I tried oracle website and documentations but nothing helped me.

Comment: Oracle 9i is outdated for 15 years I think. What is the query you run and the expected results?

Comment: Which driver are you referring to? [This support page](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/SYBPB/Support+for+Using+PowerBuilder+and+Oracle) suggests there's a native drive called `pbo90126.dll`. Do you mean that, or an Oracle-supplied driver?

Comment: Yes Oracle9i is outdated, but for some of the projects here they are still using it. I am just trying to take a count of user for user table nothing else. I am not able to get oracle 10g (10.1) drivers to check the compatibility.

Comment: I am talking about oracle supplied drivers. I have installed oracle 10g (10.2.0).

Answer (score 1):

The PowerBuilder drivers communicate with Oracle Client, not the server. Your choices for PowerBuilder drivers are O90 (Oracle 9i), O10 (Oracle 10g), and ORA (Oracle 11g).

The Oracle Client and the Oracle database server wouldn't have to match but your application will be restricted to use features supported by the client and server.

Comment: What Roland said plus keep in mind you have Oracle client and Oracle native driver in PowerBuilder. The one Roland is talking about is the PowerBuilder driver.